# To store character by character in String array

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, storing-data

I want to write a c program for splitting "23*34" string based on operator and store the numbers alone as a separate string in string array.I am the following code.

```
struct exp_details
{
        char operator[10];
        char *number[10];
}ed;

int split(int m,int n,char *str) /*m for operator index, n for str index */
{
        int i,j=0;
        for(i=n;(str[i] != ed.operator[m]) && (str[i] != '\0');i++,j++)
        {
                ed.number[m][j] = str[n];
        }
        if(str[i] != '\0')
        {
                split(m++,i++,str);
        }
        else
                return 1;
        return 0;
}
```

but this coding shows segmentation fault. it is running upto

```
ed.number[m][j] = str[n];
```

this statement.I am thinking this statement only causing problem. I think, My logic is correct.But i don't know how to rectify it. Please Help me. Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't initializing `j`.

Comment: It does not make different in output.

Comment: j seems initialized: `int i,j=0;`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to initialize `j` in your for loop: -

```
for(i=n, j = 0;(str[i] != ed.operator[m]) && (str[i] != '\0');i++,j++)
```

Also, I see some problem with your recursive call. In the statement below: -

```
split(m++,i++,str);
```

You are passing the value `m++` for `operator index`. So, here you assume that the operators in your string will appear in the same order as they are listed in your `char operator[10]` array. Which is plain wrong.

**For e.g: -**

If your operator array contains: - `{'*', '+', '/', '-'}`. And your string is: - `23*45-30+29`, then when you split your string on first operator - `*`, then on the next invocation, you are passing `+` as operator, as it comes second in your `operator array`. Now, on the next run, your loop will iterate till it finds `+` in your string, and thus it will add - `45-30` in your `numbers` array. So, there's the mistake.

You probably need to test for every character in string while iterating, whether it is present in `operator` array or not. Else you would end up storing some `operators` in your `numbers` array as well.

Answer (score 0):

The incrementation here is meaningless

```
 split(m++,i++,str);
```

since m and i are local and you increment them *after* you call the `split()` function.

you should also check the bounds when you address the array, make sure they are inside the valid
range i.e. 0..9

```
assert( m >= 0 && m <= 9 );
assert( j >= 0 && j <= 9 );
assert( n >= 0 && n <= 9 );

ed.number[m][j] = str[n]
```

better still setup a constant for your arrays

```
#define MAXSIZE 10

struct exp_details
{
        char operator[MAXSIZE];
        char *number[MAXSIZE];
} ed;

...
assert( m >= 0 && m < MAXSIZE );
assert( j >= 0 && j < MAXSIZE );
assert( n >= 0 && n < MAXSIZE );
```